# Making RSA key based on a password

Tags: c#, security, encryption, rsa

So I'm looking for a solution to make an RSA Key based on a password, so I can generate the same RSA Key every time.

I need it to decrypt some encrypted stuff when the user enters the right password, instead of giving them a private key file.

looked around the web and didn't find sth that works for me, would appreciate any help.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2004/04/14/generating-a-key-from-a-password/

Comment: Generate a key pair then encrypt the private key with a symmetric algorithm and use that key as the password?

Comment: It sounds like you want AES with a key derived via a KDF, like Rfc2898DeriveBytes (PBKDF2), not RSA at all.

Comment: @AlexNetkachov That seems to be a rc2 solution rather than a rsa one..

Comment: @AlexK.Seems interesting but I'd rather not giving a private key, even encrypted.

Comment: @bartonjs I'm using some classes to encrypt big files as fast as possible, but those algorithms only work via rsa.

Comment: RSA is designed to (can only) operate on very small amounts of data in isolation and is certainly not fast ... I think your fundamental approach may need adjusting as RSA seems a weird choice.

Comment: I have encountered this request before, and it's usually badly thought through. It's almost always better to generate an RSA keypair from a cryptographically secure randomizer and then protect the private key using a password-based protection scheme like PBKDF2. There are a very few use cases where this might make sense, like a memoryless token that cannot store any data at all.

Comment: @AlexK. I wanted to use this solution, but with a password instead of a key file, might be silly but I'm new to the whole encryption stuff so.. http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/20031101-0151.html

Comment: @JamesKPolk that kinda makes sense to me thanks for your response

Comment: @AlexK. this is the actual code that I wanted to modify if you think the first link is too boring to read: http://pages.infinit.net/ctech/crypt.cs